# Network-Boot without DHCP, remote TFTP

Tags: tftp, network-boot

I know there is a way to boot a RPi without DHCP, when i set an static TFTP_IP.
But can i set an remote TFTP Server?

So my goal is: Connect RPi to the Network. Get files from remote TFTP and boot from it

Comment: https://linuxhit.com/raspberry-pi-pxe-boot-netbooting-a-pi-4-without-an-sd-card/

Comment: Yes. As long at the TFTP is directly accessible and installed/configured correctly.